# Learning JS and confused about when to use return statements

Tags: javascript, return

I just finished learning about functions and I'm a bit confused about using return statements and variables in functions.

```
function test1(frag1, frag2) {
    return frag1 + frag2;
}

function test2(frag1, frag2) {
    message = frag1 + frag2;
}

alert(test1("this one used", " a return"));

test2("this one used ", "a variable")
alert(message);
```

Other than calling test2 outside the alert, is there any difference between using return and putting what I need inside a variable? I was learning that to get data from a function, I had to use a return statement. So how does test2 work?

You can only use return to get one thing from a function, right? So, could I use test2 to get multiple things out? Like this:

```
function test2(a, b, c) {
  message1 = a + b;
  message2 = b + c;
  message3 = a + c;
}
```

Or, am I just over thinking this/just wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The main reason to prefer the first solution over the second one is maintainability: If you have multiple functions writing/appending to the same global variable, you're just calling for trouble with inconsistencies.

Comment: You are not getting multiple things out of the function. It is setting multiple global variables.

Comment: If you want multiple things you should return a hash.  Manipulating global variables like this is a bad idea because you could get into race conditions.

Comment: You can only `return` a single value, but that value may be a type that encapsulates other values (object/array); http://jsbin.com/regiwe/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] is there any difference between using return and putting what I need inside a variable?

Yes.

If you use global variables, e.g., variables not declared with a `var` in a function, that variable will be created in the global scope. This means you may accidentally overwrite a variable with the same name, and can lead to all *sorts* of difficult-to-diagnose bugs. Global scope is usually a Bad Thing.

`test2` "works" because `message` is in the global scope, this available everywhere. Einstein would call this "spooky action at a distance", and it makes code much harder to reason about, e.g., "this variable has changed–how? Why? Where? Under what circumstances?" all become more difficult to answer.

Using `return` statements and keeping places where value modifications change centralized and contained within the smallest scope(s) possible make reasoning about what's happening much easier.

Comment: Love the Einstein references.  I use ALOT of globals, but I do agree - stay well away from them if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding global variables, such as "message" in your example, is a much much cleaner approach to programming.

Using function return values allows you to display multiple different messages without 'side effects'.

The side affect in this case is that the variable 'message' can only hold ONE message and display it at any given time.

Consider this (clean approach):

```
function sqr(n) {
    return n * n;
}

function msg1() {
    return "Hello 1";
}

function addIt(n1, n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
}

alert(sqr(5));
alert(msg1());
alert(addIt(5, 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its about scope. The reason the first example you provided works is because of the lack of scoping of `message`. If you define message as you did, it inherits the global window object, and therefore is accessible by everyone and everything:

```
function notSoPrivate(){
    message = 'test';
}

console.log(message); // logs 'test'
```

However, if you preface the declaration of the variable with the word `var`, it scopes it locally to the object / function it is in:

```
function morePrivate(){
    var message = 'test';   
}

console.log(message); // logs undefined
```

This allows you to perform multiple actions within the function without polluting the global `window` object, which is **highly** recommended.

If you wanted to return multiple items, you can return an array:

```
function test2(a, b, c) {
    var message1 = a + b,
        message2 = b + c,
        message3 = a + c;

    return [message1,message2,message3];
}

console.log(test2(1,2,3)[0]); // logs 3
```

or my preferred option, an object:

```
function test2(a, b, c) {
    var m1 = a + b,
        m2 = b + c,
        m3 = a + c;

    return {
        message1:m1,
        message2:m2,
        message3:m3
    };
}

console.log(test2(1,2,3).message1); // logs 3
```

Hopefully this helped!

Answer (score 0):

There is mainly two differences between using a return value and using a variable for the output:

- It's a lot easier to follow what the code does when you use a return value.
- To return a value in a variable it has to be global, and you should try to keep the use of global variables to a minimum.

When you use a variable for output, you need to know where the function puts the value to be able to follow the code. Just looking at the code that calls the function gives no hint that there is a relation between the function and the output:

```
test2("this one used ", "a variable")
; oh? where did message come from all of a sudden?
alert(message);
```

When you use a return value it's clear that the value comes from the function, so looking at the code tells you all you need to know on how the output is delivered:

```
var message = test2("this one used ", "a variable")
alert(message);
```

---

If you want to return multiple values from a function you can use an array or an object:

```
function test2(a, b, c) {
  return {
    message1: a + b,
    message2: b + c,
    message3: a + c
  };
}
```

You still need to know what the object contains to use the return value, but at least it's clearly visible how the output is delivered:

```
var o = test2("See how ", "I control where ", "it goes");
alert(o.message2);
```